# How to make tkinter canvas text variable in function

Tags: javascript, python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to pass different strings to canvas text that has been created within a grid using a loop function.  The text is bound to event handlers, and the print proves that it should be able to change when the event is triggered, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Consider the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def create_grid():
    rows=2
    cols=2
    canvasID = 0
    for r in range(rows):
        c=0
        for col in range(cols):

            cv=Canvas(bg='white',width=200,height=150)
            cv.grid(row=r,column=c)

            imageFile=PhotoImage(width=200,height=150)
            imageFile.put('black',to=(0,0,197,147))

            cv.image=imageFile
            cv.create_image(200/2,150/2,anchor=CENTER,image=imageFile)
            txt=cv.create_text(200/2,150/2,fill='white',anchor=CENTER,font=("Arial",18,'bold'),text=var.get())

            def enter_lambda(canvasID):
                return lambda event:on_enter(event,canvasID)
            def leave_lambda(canvasID):
                return lambda event:on_leave(event,canvasID)

            cv.bind("<Enter>", enter_lambda(canvasID))
            cv.bind("<Leave>", leave_lambda(canvasID))

            canvasID+=1
            c+=1
        r+=1

def on_enter(event,canvasID,*args):
    var="in"
    print var,str(canvasID)
def on_leave(event,canvasID,*args):
    var="out"
    print var,str(canvasID)

root=Tk()
app=Frame(root)

var=StringVar()
var.set("out")

create_grid()
root.mainloop()
```

A similar question can be found at [How to add a Tkinter Text Variable in canvas text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518976/how-to-add-a-tkinter-text-variable-in-canvas-text) although using this method hasn't worked and I can't figure out why.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to happen. Can you describe the effect? When I move into square #2, what's supposed to happen?

Comment: To clarify, the effect should be if you move into square #2 the text should change to "IN 2", for square #3 "IN 3", etc.  Also, when you leave the square it should be able to indicate which square was left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is for the word in the square to be "IN" when the mouse is inside the square, and "OUT" when the mouse is outside the square.

If that is so, there are many ways to accomplish that. The simplest is to pass the id of the text item to  your callbacks, and use `itemconfigure` to change the value. You don't need to use a `StrngVar` to make this work.

For example:

```
txt=cv.create_text(..., text="OUT")
...
def enter_lambda(canvasID, textID):
    return lambda event:on_enter(event,canvasID, textID)
def leave_lambda(canvasID, textID):
    return lambda event:on_leave(event,canvasID, textID)
...
cv.bind("<Enter>", enter_lambda(canvasID, txt))
cv.bind("<Leave>", leave_lambda(canvasID, txt))
...
def on_enter(event,canvasID, txt):
    cv = event.widget
    cv.itemconfigure(txt, text="IN %s" % canvasID)

def on_leave(event,canvasID, txt):
    cv = event.widget
    cv.itemconfigure(txt, text="OUT %s" % canvasID)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution definitely works for having the text change from "OUT" to "IN".  However I was trying to have the text display the state ("IN" or "OUT") and identify which canvas was being triggered.  For example "IN 3" or "IN 1".  Since lambda only accepts one arg, what would be the solution here?

Comment: @zarf.snackler: you can pass as many arguments as you want to a lambda function.

Comment: Ah sorry of course it can, I'm quite new at this and I missed putting an argument in the enter_lambda function.  Your edited script does what I was hoping for.  Thanks!